# Deprecated RDF unintentionally removed

Tags: upgrading, 10, rdf

I am prepping my company site to move from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10. I am working with the Upgrade Status module to make sure the site is ready. In the process, I needed to uninstall the Core RDF module as it is deprecated. I uninstalled the Core RDF module and replaced with the RDF module that is compatible with 10. My staging site has the new RDF module and seems to be working as intended. Upon review, I noticed the Core RDF module is gone. I am thinking I messed up, and must have not only uninstalled the module, but unintentionally removed the module. So, my Core RDF module is still installed on my Production site. I believe this will cause a configuration issue when I attempt to push my staging site to production. Does anyone have an idea on how I can require the Core RDF module as it is deprecated, or implement a fix so I won't incur this config issue when I push from my staging to production environment? I have been searching and unable to find a fix. Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Drupal 10, the RDF module has been removed from the core modules. The [Resource Description Framework (RDF)](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdf) module contains the same code. If you want to use the RDF module with Drupal 10, you need to use the contributed module.

Comment: I do not completely understand this question.

Comment: @cilefen I guess the OP does not understand the RDF module has been **deprecated** in Drupal 9 and **removed** from Drupal 10. When upgrading to Drupal 10, the module is indeed removed. What the OP needs to know is how to upgrade to Drupal 10 and use the contributed module that replaced the core RDF module without losing its configuration.

Comment: I am not sure. They wrote "I uninstalled the Core RDF module and replaced with the RDF module that is compatible with 10."